# Trying to consume .net core web api but getting this error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to consume an ASP.NET Core Web API from my ASP.NET MVC web application and getting this error:

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(_apiBaseUrl))
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Error occurs on below line     
        appList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Application>>(apiResponse);
    }
}
```

I call this in Postman: https://localhost:5001/api/Application

And get this response:

```
[
  {
    "app_id": 2,
    "start_date": "2021-08-12T00:00:00",
    "end_date": "2021-10-12T00:00:00",
    "status": "Not started",
    "dep_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "app_id": 3,
    "start_date": "2021-07-11T00:00:00",
    "end_date": "2021-09-23T00:00:00",
    "status": "Ended",
    "dep_id": 2,
  }
]
```

This JSON seems correct to me. If not correct me please.

I followed this method available on [yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api/#read).

My api controller class contains this to make sure api responses with json:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
```

"value: <. Path" Is this part means response is XML and not Json?

I am really confused. Provide information to solve this error.

Comment: Hi @Gokay Umutlu, please share your Application model and what is your web api code. It seems your response not match the model type.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that misbehaving line and inspect the value of `apiResponse` - is it json or xml?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have a bad response status code. Try this code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    var baseAddress = "http://localhost:5001";
    var api = "api/Application";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Application>>(json);
    }
}
```